# Reactで複数の画像を表示し、一枚ずつ横スライドをできるようにしたい

Tags: react-jsx

[image: jsxで並べた画像]

現在は複数の画像をwidth70%で横6枚まで表示しそれを超えると改行される状態にしています。

Comment: 関連するコードも質問を編集して含めるようにしてください。